# Why does has_nav_menu return false when get_registered_nav_menus shows the opposite?

Tags: theme-development, menus

I'm working on a new theme to replace an old one.  The existing theme has custom menus and I can't figure out why in my new theme a call to `has_nav_menu` is always coming back false.

In my `functions.php`, I register the menus:

```
    function register_menus() {

        register_nav_menus(
            array(
                'global-nav' => 'Global Navigation',
                'footer-nav' =>  'Footer Links',
                'sitemap' =>  'Site Map',
                'share-ideas' => 'Share Ideas'
            ));
    }

    add_action( 'init', 'register_menus' );
```

Then in a test page, I have the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <?php
    if ( has_nav_menu( 'global-nav' ) )
    {
        echo '<h1>menu found</h1>';

    } else {
        echo '<h1>menu not found, menus registered are:</h1>';
        $menus = get_registered_nav_menus();

        foreach ( $menus as $location => $description ) {

            echo $location . ': ' . $description . '<br />';
        }
    }
    ?>

</div>
```

The weird thing: while `has_nav_menu` always returns false, the `get_registered_nav_menus` loop shows the locations exist.

Also, in the admin->menus screen, the menus all show up fine.

So clearly I'm missing something as `get_registered_nav_menus` says I have registered them properly **but** `has_nav_menu` fails.  Unfortunately, I can't figure out what step I might have skipped.

Comment: At the risk of asking a stupid question: I know you've created the menus, but have you assigned them to menu locations? That's what has_nav_menu is actually testing.

Comment: There are no stupid questions. But `has_nav_menu` on the codex says is checks 'Whether a registered nav menu location has a menu assigned(true) or not(false).'  Isn't that what `register_nav_menus` is doing?  Assigning a location (the key in the array) to a menu (the value)?  In other themes, I've used a similar construction...which is why I'm confused.

Comment: `register_nav_menus` creates your empty menu locations, but it doesn't assign any particular menus to them. You have to do that as a separate step on the Admin->Menus screen, either in the Manage Locations tab or at the bottom of each individual menu's screen.

Comment: Yep, and those show the menus all have assignments.  I appreciate the feedback and the double-checking.  I'm sure I'm missing something trivial like this...but still unsure what... :(

Comment: It might be a new bug - I'm having the same issue with a site that was working fine in 3.9.1, but the menus stopped displaying in 4.0.1. About `get_registered_nav_menus` returning something different — it looks like `has_nav_menus` checks for the menu location in `_wp_registered_nav_menus` first (see more on [core.trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0.1/src/wp-includes/nav-menu.php#L0)). Anyway... @MatthewBakaitis did you find a fix? I'm just commenting out `has_nav_menus` for now.

Comment: For the record: As of this comment I have not found a solution to this...still looking!